# Solving a set of Trigonometric Equations in polar coordinate

Tags: equation-solving, trigonometry

I have been having difficulties solving a set of trigonometric equations. My problem contains 6 equations and 6 unknowns in polar coordinate and I am not sure if I am writing the angles in the correct format and my code does not work.

```
ClearAll;
s1 = 0.067;
theta1 = -152 Degree;
s2 = 0.015;
theta2 = -130 Degree;
s3 = 0.0078;
theta3 = -165 Degree;
exp1 = ExpandAll[
   s1*Cos[theta1 Degree] - 
     s1*s*Cos[theta1 Degree + thetas Degree + 180 Degree] - 
     d*Cos[thetad Degree] + 
     d*s*Cos[thetad Degree + thetas Degree + 180 Degree] == 
    1 - r*Cos[thetar Degree + 180 Degree]];
exp2 = ExpandAll[
   s2*Cos[theta2 Degree] - (0.3)*s2*s*
      Cos[theta2 Degree + thetas Degree + 180 Degree] - 
     d*Cos[thetad Degree] + (0.3)*d*s*
      Cos[thetad Degree + thetas Degree + 
        180 Degree] == (0.3) - (0.3)*r*
      Cos[thetar Degree + 180 Degree]];
exp3 = ExpandAll[
   s3*Cos[theta3 Degree] - (0.0001)*s3*s*
      Cos[theta3 Degree + thetas Degree] - 
     d*Cos[thetad Degree] + (0.0001)*d*s*
      Cos[thetad Degree + thetas Degree] == (0.0001) - (0.0001)*r*
      Cos[thetar Degree]];
exp4 = ExpandAll[
   s1*Sin[theta1 Degree] - 
     s1*s*Sin[theta1 Degree + thetas Degree + 180 Degree] - 
     d*Sin[thetad Degree] + 
     d*s*Sin[thetad Degree + thetas Degree + 180 Degree] == 
    1 - r*Sin[thetar Degree + 180 Degree]];
exp5 = ExpandAll[
   s2*Sin[theta2 Degree] - (0.3)*s2*s*
      Sin[theta2 Degree + thetas Degree + 180 Degree] - 
     d*Sin[thetad Degree] + (0.3)*d*s*
      Sin[thetad Degree + thetas Degree + 
        180 Degree] == (0.3) - (0.3)*r*
      Sin[thetar Degree + 180 Degree]];
exp6 = ExpandAll[
   s3*Sin[theta3 Degree] - (0.0001)*s3*s*
      Sin[theta3 Degree + thetas Degree] - 
     d*Sin[thetad Degree] + (0.0001)*d*s*
      Sin[thetad Degree + thetas Degree] == (0.0001) - (0.0001)*r*
      Sin[thetar Degree]];
v = Total[{exp1, exp2, exp3, exp4, exp5, exp6} /. 
    Equal[l_, r_] -> Norm[1 - (r)]];
NMinimize[v, {s, thetas, r, thetar, d, thetad}, MaxIterations -> 10^3]
```

Comment: What's the problem? On my machine the code runs without an error and produces a result

Comment: Also, you define `theta1 = -152 Degree` and then use `Cos[theta1 Degree +...]` which means that you're multiplying by $180/2\pi$ twice instead of once. `theta1` (and all the other angles) is already in radians so you should use `Cos[theta1+...]`

Comment: @yohbs thank you for your response. This code runs without any error but the answer is not correct and if you change any of the initial values for theta or s, there is no change in the final solution. I also noticed Mathematica does not give the correct answer for Cos[-120Degree] or any function like that. So I don't know how to write the appropriate format for these trigonometric functions.

Comment: Let us look, how your exp1 is evaluated: `0.0669 - d Cos[\[Degree] thetad] + 
  0.067 s Cos[152 \[Degree]^2 - \[Degree] thetas] - d s Cos[\[Degree] thetad + \[Degree] thetas] == 1 + r Cos[\[Degree] thetar]` . One finds a lot of strange things indicating to syntax errors, such as the constructs `152 \[Degree]^2` or `\[Degree] thetas`. The first one is already explained by yohbs earlier. To remove the second do not type `Degree` after the variable at all. Your result will anyway be in grad. Besides that, either do not use the `ExpandAll` function, or use it with the option `Trig->True`.

Comment: Finally, for me `Cos[-120 Degree]` evaluates to `-1/2` as well as `Cos[-2 Pi/3]` which is expected.

Comment: Thanks, @AlexeiBoulbitch. I tried solving this set of equations using NSolve and using your help all the difficulties with phases go away.

Comment: Here is my new code:

Comment: I do not see the new code. Do you know that you can edit the old code by clicking the button "edit" under your original pose? Further, if your aim is a numeric solution, try `FindRoot` instead of the `NSolve`.